# Problems getting JSON with getJSON()

Tags: php, jquery, json, drupal

Im trying to get my javascript to read the JSON from a url on another page of my site. The plan is to have an image with a link that's stored on that url and have that displayed on the front page of my site. I was able to do this before for a similar display so I thought it would be easy this time. For some reason, getJSON isn't even reading the JSON from my URL and I'm pretty sure it's correct, I modified the code from the previous display.

This code creates the JSON (in PHP):

```
function tf_feature_url_callback() {
  // get last row from the table
  $qry = 'SELECT * FROM tf_daily_featured_item ORDER BY fiid DESC LIMIT 1';
  $result = db_query($qry);
  $linkData = db_fetch_object($result);
  $data = array('link'=>$linkData->link);
  // encode the data as a json string
  $json_link = json_encode($data);
  echo $json_link;
}
```

And the JSON is displayed on a page as:

```
{"link":"test.com"}
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
// this is the url with JSON data
var urlURL = '/tf_feature/get_url';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(urlURL, function(data) {
        alert("TEST");
    });
});
```

Im not getting an alert so i'm pretty sure my javascript isn't even entering the getJSON function.

Is there a limit to the amount of times you can call getJSON on a website? I'm calling it a few times already.

***EDIT:***

This is my callback (I'm using Drupal and this is a module)

```
// callback for the url
  $items['tf_feature/get_url'] = array(
    'title' => 'Featured Item URL Callback',
    'page callback' => 'tf_feature_url_callback',
    'access arguments' => 'access content',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );
```

Comment: Check the network traffic if the request you're looking for is a) fired and b) gets the data back. Normally there is not such a limit, you can fire as many requests as like (and as your browser is able to fire and your server is able to take). Read: If you bomb your server so it breaks down or you bomb your browser so it breaks down, things tend to not work.

Comment: Also look into `console.log` and how you use the developer tools in your browser.

Comment: Yes, improve your debugging skills, that will help you most.

Comment: How are you executing the `tf_feature_url_callback` function on your server?

Comment: Im using Drupal so it's a callback in the hook_menu function of the module.

Comment: @user: I added the drupal tag to your question. And as it's jquery, it's javacript, so I removed that, same for getjson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first off I have to say that I winced at `urlURL` ;-)  But moving on, there's just not enough info here to fully diagnose your problem.  Most likely your code isn't getting run; perhaps the page has already loaded by the time your onReady runs?  Then again, maybe not; without more info it's hard to say.

I highly recommend either getting the Firebug plug-in for Firefox, or using the Chrome (built-in) developer tools.  Either of these will be able to tell you whether the AJAX request is happening or not, and if it is happening what's coming back.  Further more, you can add `debugger` lines to your code, and both those tool will pause when the hit those lines, allowing you to see what's going on (you can inspect variable values and such).

Try using one of those tools, and I really expect you'll be able to debug this problem yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I know. Im still testing it so it'll change later.

Comment: Safari has developer tools built in too. Don't know if it's comparable to firebug and chrome inspector, but you perhaps you could include this into your answer.

Comment: I like chromes tools. Im looking into the inspector right now

Comment: @11684 I've never used Safari's tools, so I can't really speak to them (but hey, they can't be worse than Microsoft's right?).  Thanks for your comment though, as future Safari-using readers might prefer to try those tools.

Comment: @user great ... and I was just ribbing you about `urlURL` :-)

Comment: I'm using them and it has the same console as chrome (well, not exactly the same of course, but it looks and feels the same), but I have yet to discover how to inspect variable values and such.

Comment: jQuery's `ready` handler will execute the function immediately if the page has already loaded when it reaches it.

Comment: It looks like the url with the data is being requested and it's waiting.

Comment: Well, that's rather odd; either you're misinterpreting what your tool is telling you, or you have a rogue server-side (PHP) script.  I'd try browsing the exact URL of your AJAX request; if your browser just waits endlessly then you know your tool worked but your server-side is broken.  If you do get a response, then you have more debugging to do :-)